# How do I allow my custom entity to be rendered using an entity_reference field?

Tags: 8, entities

Using Drupal 8, I created a custom entity, configured a few view modes for it, and then added an entity_reference field from another entity to my custom entity.

In the display configuration for my entity_reference field, I've selected "Rendered entity" and chosen a valid view mode for my entity, but I'm not getting any content when I view the host entity.

I also created an entity_reference field on my host entity that points to the default "Basic Page" node type (as a positive control) and that field shows up when I view the host entity.

Comment: Do you have an EntityViewBuilder in your content entity annotation? See http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/comment/src/Entity/Comment.php#n29